# Android CalendarView selector background

Tags: android, xml, calendarview

I have a CalendarView object and I would like to change the circle's background from XML.
I read that I have to implement my own object to do this simple task. How can I easily do this task without implementing my own?
[image: I would like to change the circle's color]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new style in your styles.xml

```
<style name="MyCalanderTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/SetYourColorHere</item>
</style>
```

Then while opening DatePickerDialog pass in that style like this

```
final DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), R.style.MyCalanderTheme);
```

Replace SetYourColorHere with whatever color you want to set as date background

Or you can set the Main Styles accentColor too... But if you want to use different colors for apps accentColor and for data background then follow the above approach.